# android error when making maps application

Tags: android

why there is error when making maps android application only....
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
R cannot be resolved to a variable  MainActivity.java   /gps/src/com/example/gps    line 13 Java Problem

Comment: `Clean` Project. Check `XML` files for possible error, etc. There are a lot of answers about this issue if you just make a `search`

Comment: this error appear only when making Google map application<<why ?